# Hibernate assigned generator

Tags: java, hibernate

The generator element in the hibernate mapping file is supposed to be used to determine how the primary key is generated. Why is the default value *assigned* bad for detached and transient objects?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the application to assign identifiers, as opposed to having Hibernate generate them, you can use the assigned generator. This special generator uses the identifier value already assigned to the object's identifier property. The generator is used when the primary key is a natural key instead of a surrogate key. This is the default behavior if you do not specify a  element.

The assigned generator makes Hibernate use unsaved-value="undefined". This forces Hibernate to go to the database to determine if an instance is transient or detached, unless there is a version or timestamp property, or you define Interceptor.isUnsaved().

Comment: The statement _This forces Hibernate to go to the database to determine if an instance is transient or detached_, implies that Hibernate uses unsaved-value to determine if an object is detached. This can't be correct because Hibernate uses unsaved-value to determine if an object is transient.

Comment: Oh...I get it. If the unsaved-value matches, Hibernate knows that its a transient object and uses INSERT. If it does, Hibernate knows that its detached and uses UPDATE.